# If $|f(x)|$ is a measurable function defined on a measurable set $E\subset \mathbb{R}^d$, is $f(x)$ also measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

If $|f(x)|$ is a measurable function defined on a measurable set $E\subset \mathbb{R}^d$, is $f(x)$ also measurable?

***Answer*** No. Consider the nonmeasurable set $\mathcal{N} \subset [0,1]$, and the function
\begin{align*}
    f(x) = \begin{cases}
         \quad \phantom{-}1, \quad x \in \mathcal{N} \\
         \quad -1, \quad x \in [0,1] \setminus \mathcal{N}
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
Here $g(x) = |f(x)| \equiv 1$ on $[0,1]$ and therefore $g(x) = |f(x)|$ is measurable, since $g^{-1}(1) = \{x \in [0,1]: g(x) <= 1\} = [0,1]$, which is a measurable set. But clearly, $f^{-1}(1) = \mathcal{N}$, which is not measurable.

---

Please check the validity of my proof.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Just checking the validity of my proof.

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: You might want to add that the set $\mathcal{N}$ should be in $E$ and maybe expand on its existence. (If we are considering measurability wrt. $\mathcal{P}({\mathbb{R}^d})$ the statement is true...)

Comment: OT: The OP asked clearly for a review of his/her proof, and so the downvote seems inappropriate. In fact. the downvoting here is becoming egregious. It defeats the purpose of the site, reduces the traffic and causes users to scroll by interesting questions.